# AutoMapper in Infrastructure project and error 'Missing type map configuration'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I have all my db entities in `Infrastructure` project (important: it's db-first approach). My dto entities are located in `Application` project. What I want to do is to map Db entities to Dto entities but when I do so I get an error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration
> or unsupported mapping.
> Mapping types:
> List 1 -> UserDto
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[RegionManagement.Persistence.ModelsDb.User,
> RegionManagement.Persistence, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]] ->
> RegionManagement.Domain.Entities.Administration.UserEntries.UserDto

At the first glance everything looks ok and I wonder where the problem lies.

I do the mapping in 2 places in my app: in `Infrastructure` project (db entity -> dto entity) and `Application` project (dto entity -> other dto/vm entities). Everything worked fine until I added mapping in `Infrastucture`. So basically I have db entity `User` and dto entity `UserDto`. I created a repository in `Infrastructure` project where I map those entities and mapping profile in seperate class:

**UserRepository.cs**

```
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository<UserDto>
    {
        protected readonly RegionManagementDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public UserRepository(RegionManagementDbContext dbContext, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<IReadOnlyList<UserDto>> ListAllAsync()
        {
            var dbDataList = await _dbContext.Users.ToListAsync();
            var mapList = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(dbDataList);
            return (IReadOnlyList<UserDto>)mapList;
        }
    }
```

**MappingProfile.cs**

```
    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
        }
    }
```

and the I register service as an extension of `IServiceCollection` (I still do it in Infrastructure project), as shown below:

**InfrastructureServiceRegistration.cs**

```
    public static class InfrastructureServiceRegistration
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddPersistenceServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<RegionManagementDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("RegionManagementConnectionString")));

            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            services.AddScoped<IUserRepository<UserDto>, UserRepository>();

            return services;
        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs**
(`AddApplicationServices` is where I registered `AutoMapper` for `Application` project):

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddApplicationServices();
            services.AddInfrastructureServices(Configuration);
            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "RegionManagement.Api", Version = "v1" });
            });

        }
```

Error indicates that something is wrong with mapping `User` -> `UserDto` but have no idea what it could be.

I scan assembly for profiles in this place:  `services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());` but it doesn't help.

Comment: Are you sure you dont have your old UserDto class hanging around somewhere?

Comment: Could you be more precise? Where it could hang around?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can register profiles in Automapper from different assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498337/how-can-register-profiles-in-automapper-from-different-assemblies)

Comment: I scan for assembly here: `services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());`  and it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types:
> List 1 -> UserDto

says that you're trying to map a List into a UserDto.

This is the line with the problem:

```
var mapList = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(dbDataList);
```

Try to rewrite it this way:

```
var mapList = dbDataList.Select(_mapper.Map<UserDto>)
```

Comment: Perfect answer! That made me thinking that I forgot to return a list of UserDto, I overlooked it. So I changed to `var mapList = _mapper.Map<List<UserDto>>(dbDataList);` and it works fine. Thanks for your hint!